# Seeking NYC Subway Line Station Order data

Tags: data, united-states, linear-referencing, transportation, order

I've currently got data on the NYC subway stations (including name, position, and how many people entered and existed during a timeframe). Also, I have the data on which stations have which train lines. However, I don't have the order of these stations on the line.

Is there anywhere where this data is already formatted in some way that can be easily used programmatically?

I could put them in order in some csv file on my own, but I'd rather avoid that if I can.

Answer (score 1):

**MTA data in GIS format**

> But the GTFS “stops.txt” file only includes station names, not a list
>   of routes. The “stop_times.txt” file includes trip IDs that can be
>   joined with the “trips.txt” file to identify routes as well as stops. 
>   But this represents more than 500,000 records (one for each trip by
>   each route stopping at each station).  If you dissolved those on the
>   stop_id field (using standard grouping or dissolve functions in Excel
>   or Access, for example), you’d only get the first route ID per
>   station, not a comma-separated inline list like I wanted.

Solution
USE  SQL’s “`COALESCE`” function

http://spatialityblog.com/2010/07/20/more-mta-data-in-gis-format/

reference (lines)
http://spatialityblog.com/2010/07/08/mta-gis-data-update/

Data set with the stops:
https://wfs.gc.cuny.edu/SRomalewski/MTA_GISdata/June2010_update/nyctsubwaystops_100627_curcleaned.zip

Full Credit to:
**Steven Romalewski**

Comment: The order in either direction. I mean I'm looking for a the data to show which stations are 1 stop away from which other stations.

Comment: The `stop_sequence` value tells you the order of stops for each individual train run, so use that in conjunction with `stop_id`.